# Remove first n bytes from a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

How can I remove the first *n* number of bytes from a ByteBuffer without changing or lowering the capacity? The result should be that the 0th byte is the *n+1* byte. Is there a better data type in Java to do this type of action?

Comment: Do you want to set each of the first `n` bytes to zero, or to skip the first `n` bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void removeBytesFromStart(ByteBuffer bf, int n) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = n; i < bf.position(); i++) {
        bf.put(index++, bf.get(i));
        bf.put(i, (byte)0);
    }
    bf.position(index);
}
```

Or something like this:

```
public void removeBytesFromStart2(ByteBuffer bf, int n) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = n; i < bf.limit(); i++) {
        bf.put(index++, bf.get(i));
        bf.put(i, (byte)0);
    }
    bf.position(bf.position()-n);
}
```

This uses the absolute [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get%28int%29) and [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28int,%20byte%29) method of the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class and sets the [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) at next write position.

Note that the absolute `put` method is optional, which means that a class that extends the abstract class `ByteBuffer` may not provide an implementation for it, for example it might throw a `ReadOnlyBufferException`.

Whether you choose to loop till [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28%29) or till [limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit%28%29) depends on how you use the buffer, for example if you manually set the [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) you might want to use loop till `limit`. If you do not then looping till `position` is enough and more efficient.

Here is some testings:

```
@Test
public void removeBytesFromStart() {
    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    int expectedCapacity = bf.capacity();
    bf.put("abcdefg".getBytes());

    ByteBuffer expected = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    expected.put("defg".getBytes());

    removeBytesFromStart(bf, 3);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedCapacity, bf.capacity());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, bf.compareTo(expected));
}

@Test
public void removeBytesFromStartInt() {
    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    int expectedCapacity = bf.capacity();
    bf.putInt(1);
    bf.putInt(2);
    bf.putInt(3);
    bf.putInt(4);

    ByteBuffer expected = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    expected.putInt(2);
    expected.putInt(3);
    expected.putInt(4);

    removeBytesFromStart2(bf, 4);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedCapacity, bf.capacity());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, bf.compareTo(expected));
}
```

Comment: The `removeBytesFromStart` function works perfectly! Thank you for adding the unit tests too!

Answer (score 4):

I think the method you are looking for is [the ByteBuffer's compact() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact%28%29)

Even though the documentation says:

*"The bytes between the buffer's current position and its limit, if any, are copied to the beginning of the buffer. That is, the byte at index p = position() is copied to index zero, the byte at index p + 1 is copied to index one, and so forth until the byte at index limit() - 1 is copied to index n = limit() - 1 - p. The buffer's position is then set to n+1 and its limit is set to its capacity."*

I am not sure that this method realy does that, because when I debug it seems like the method just does `buffer.limit = buffer.capacity`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to shift all the element to the begining of the buffer? Like this:

```
    int n = 4;
    //allocate a buffer of capacity 10 
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(10); 

    // add data to buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < b.limit(); i++) {
        b.put((byte) i);
    }

    // print buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < b.limit(); i++) {
        System.out.print(b.get(i) + " ");
    }

    //shift left the elements from the buffer
    //add zeros to the end
    for (int i = n; i < b.limit() + n; i++) {
        if (i < b.limit()) {
            b.put(i - n, b.get(i));
        } else {
            b.put(i - n, (byte) 0);
        }
    }
    //print buffer again
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.limit(); i++) {
        System.out.print(b.get(i) + " ");
    }
```

For n=4 it will print:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks andreih! I marked A4L's answer as the 'correct' due to the brevity of the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer avoids double write of bytes from `n` to `limit-n`, for the case of `n < limit/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use compact method for that. E.g.:

```
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    b.put("hello,world".getBytes());
    b.position(6);      
    b.compact();
    System.out.println(new String(b.array()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in functionality of ByteBuffer.  See below.

```
static void shiftByteBuffer(ByteBuffer bb, int numToShift) {
    bb.limit(bb.position());  // Make the buffer "full"
    bb.position(numToShift);  // Set position to numToShift so we only get rid of the first <numToShift> bytes.
    bb.compact();             // Shifts everything and resets indexes
}
```

You can test it using this method to see that it works.

```
public void shiftByteBuffer_test1() {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(10).put(new byte[]{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05});

    assertNotNull(bb);
    assertEquals(10, bb.limit());
    assertEquals(6, bb.position());
    assertEquals((byte)0x00, bb.get(0));
    assertEquals((byte)0x01, bb.get(1));
    assertEquals((byte)0x02, bb.get(2));
    assertEquals((byte)0x03, bb.get(3));
    assertEquals((byte)0x04, bb.get(4));

    PacketEmitter.shiftByteBuffer(bb, 1);

    assertEquals(10, bb.limit());
    assertEquals(5, bb.position());
    assertEquals((byte)0x01, bb.get(0));
    assertEquals((byte)0x02, bb.get(1));
    assertEquals((byte)0x03, bb.get(2));
    assertEquals((byte)0x04, bb.get(3));
}
```